# Why would a jQuery file be getting a 404 error over https but not http?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, apache

I'm hosting a `wordpress` website. Within my plugin is five `javascript` files containing `jQuery`. The permissions are set to 644. The other `javascript` files within the folder do not have the same error.

`Wordpress` updated it's `jQuery` version with `wordpress 4.5` but I do not see how that relates to this.

This just started happening this past weekend, although when I was working on it on Friday it was working just fine. The 404 error is not cached either. The headers look perfectly normal and there are no errors within `Wordpress`.

Any idea what might be causing this? For reference I'm using `Dreamhost's` `Dreampress` plan.

Answer (score 0):

I further researched the problem with the following procedure.

- Created a new file and wrote to that file 'number #1'
- Checked the file online, says 'number #1'
- Rewrote file to say 'number #2'
- Checked file online

The result happened to be that the http version said 'number #2' however the https version said 'number #2'. I then went through my SSL settings, and disabled Cloudflare's railgun feature which I had previously not read the description because it sounded like a good thing.